# Facebook cannot read my Open Graph Tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, metadata, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

Here my Website Facebook Open Graph Tags

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Áo nhũ quảng châu - 240.000 VNĐ" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Các gái nhìn nhé. 2 ảnh đầu là áo nhũ loại 2 tay gấp mép, hàng Quảng Châu tay áo k gấp mép nhé các gái. Ai nhìn cận áo cũng mê tít e Quảng Châu nên k ai qtam đến giá và chất lượng áo kia nữa" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Tuệ Thy - Xưởng Chuyên Sỉ Quần Áo Thời Trang Nam Nữ Giá Rẻ" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://xuongtuethy.com/Ao-nhu-Quang-Chau-2-loai" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://xuongtuethy.com/image/cache/catalog/Ao-nhu/Ao-nhu-Quang-Chau-www.xuongtuethy.com-2-600x315.jpg" />
<meta property="product:price:amount" content="240000.00" />
<meta property="product:price:currency" content="VND" />
<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
```

But Facebook cannot Read my Facebook Open Graph Tags when i use Facebook Debug Tool ! 
Facebook say :

> Object at URL 'http://xuongtuethy.com/Ao-nhu-Quang-Chau-2-loai' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.

Yesterday ,Facebook still reading normal until today have this error.
Does anyone can help me ? Thanks for Reading !

Comment: Seems to work fine now, the debug tool is able to fetch current information.

Comment: hjx ! Debug tool yesterday can fetch my website but today cannot fetch again ! What's happening although i did not edit anything on my website from three day ago